# Merge two QIcon

Tags: c++, qt

`QIcon` has a notion of *state*, e.g. when requesting a pixmap from a `QIcon` one can ask it for a pixmap for an `On` state (like a depressed push button) or in an `Off` state.

Creating a state-aware `QIcon` is straightforward: Just call the `QIcon::addPixmap()` member function with a suitable combination of the `mode` and `state` arguments to compose the desired pixmaps into the `QIcon`.

When using Qt's theme mechanism, however, one creates the `QIcon` using the `QIcon::fromTheme()` static member function. The icons returned by this function are not state-aware. In fact, from the Qt sources I learnt that only the `QIcon::Mode` is applied on the fly, e.g. to gray out the icon for a `Disabled` mode.

So consider I create two distinct icons from the theme, `onIcon` and `offIcon`, how could I merge them into a single `QIcon` to cover the respective `State`s?

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you use `addPixmap()`?

Comment: Because I don't have a pixmap. I only have a QIcon that *may* contain pixmaps of various sizes, or even scalable SVG content and no pixmap at all.

Comment: But why can't you take the `QIcon` returned by `fromTheme` and add the missing pixmaps you created to it?

Comment: Because I don't have the "missing pixmaps" either. I only have one `QIcon` for the *on* state and another `QIcon` for the *off* state. Both of them are created using `QIcon::fromTheme()`, though.

Comment: So take the pixmaps from each icon, and add them to a new icon using `QIcon::pixmap()` and `QIcon::addPixmap()`.

Comment: Ok. How about create icon with QIcon::fromTheme(). After that get all availabel sizes with QIcon::availableSizes(); After that get pixmaps with QIcon::pixmap(const QSize &size, Mode mode = Normal, State state = Off) const. And work with pixmap?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the [`QIcon::availableSizes`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#availableSizes) to extract all the individual pixmaps from each icon, and then assign a *role* (mode + state) to each set.

Here a basic example with just on and off states.

```
QIcon mergeIcons(const QIcon& on_icon, const QIcon& off_icon) {
  QIcon new_icon;
  const auto fn_add = [&new_icon](const QIcon& src, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state) {
    const auto sizes = src.availableSizes();
    for (const auto& size : sizes) {
      new_icon.addPixmap(src.pixmap(size), mode, state);
    }      
  };

  fn_add(on_icon, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
  fn_add(off_icon, QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);

  return new_icon;
}
```

Then simply load the source icons and merge them:

```
const QIcon on_icon("on.ico");
const QIcon off_icon("off.ico");
ui->pushButton->setIcon(mergeIcons(on_icon, off_icon));
```